# Background-image não carrega no github pages

Tags: github, background, background-image

Olá! Criei um site simples e subi para o **github pages** dele, o HTML, JS e parte do CSS estão funcionando normalmente, porém o **background-image** não carrega (localmente ele carrega normal).
Estou há horas tentando resolver e não consigo encontrar solução.

O github pages é esse: [meu site no github pages](https://loyne.github.io/IMC-Calculator-lvl1/)

O repo onde ele está é esse: [meu repositório](https://github.com/LoYne/IMC-Calculator-lvl1)

**Agradeço de coração a quem puder ajudar.**

Comment: Tente pelo caminho absoluto dessa forma!  >>>  https://github.com/LoYne/IMC-Calculator-lvl1/blob/main/img/suaImagem.jpg <<

Answer (score 1):

No seu CSS você está usando a seguinte URL:

```css
body {
    url(/img/estetoscopio-pretoebranco-mmm.jpg)
}
```

Ou seja, você está dizendo que a imagem está em `https://loyne.github.io/img/estetoscopio-pretoebranco-mmm.jpg`, pois sua URL começa com `/` então o navegador assume que o path parte do "root".

Para corrigir você pode usar a URL absoluta mencionada no parágrafo anterior, ou usar o caminho relativo:

```css
body {
    url(../img/estetoscopio-pretoebranco-mmm.jpg)
}
```

Como esse código está na pasta `css`, você tem que indicar que a pasta imagem está na pasta pai com o `..`.

Você pode entender mais sobre URLs relativas [nesse artigo da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#absolute_urls_vs_relative_urls).

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigada!! s2

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no path do seu arquivo .css.
Está dessa forma: /img/estetoscopio-pretoebranco-mmm.jpg
Quando o correto seria:../img/estetoscopio-pretoebranco-mmm.jpg
O ".." Significa para voltar uma pasta atrás já que a img não está no mesmo dir que o seu arquivo css.